# WMI Linker Error on x64

Tags: c++, wmi, 64-bit

I'm trying to use the WMI example from msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I've copied the last set of code there verbatim into a console application in VS2008.  If I have the application in release or debug for the win32 platform, it compiles (and runs) fine.  If I have it in release or debug for the x64 platform, I get the following linker errors:

```
CppConsole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IWbemConfigureRefresher
CppConsole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_WbemRefresher
CppConsole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IWbemRefresher
CppConsole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_WbemLocator
CppConsole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IWbemLocator
fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

I've already tried putting the wbemuuid.lib into the linker input directly in the project properties, but that didn't make a difference from the pragma.

Has anybody made this work with x64? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just create a new console c++ application using vs2008, x64 and compiles and runs ok. So your issue must be related to some missing file or configuration.

Comment: Try checking which version of the Microsoft SDK do you have installed and if the `wbemuuid.lib` file exist in this location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\x64`

Comment: @RRUZ I only have up to 5.0 installed, and don't have the x64 directory at all.  I'll look up where to D/L the MS SDK from and see if that works.  If you reply with an answer below rather than a comment, I'll likely be marking yours as "correct" if this is the root of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give credit to RRUZ for this, as he/she at least put me on the right track, but as they haven't posted an answer-answer (just a comment) I can't click them for credit.

Basically, because of the work environment I'm in, the project directories are set up in a "non-standard" way.  There was already a copy of wbemuuid.lib in another directory that was not the correct version (not x64), and that directory was higher on the library include list, thus never getting to the right Windows Platform library directory.

So if you ever have problems with x86 vs x64 and library includes, check your directories and check the ORDER of them as well.