# How can I compile CEF library with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, chromium-embedded

I followed Sga's answer [How to use Chromium Embedded Framework with Visual Studio 2017 (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142685/how-to-use-chromium-embedded-framework-with-visual-studio-2017-c) to compile Cef with Visual Studio 2017. However, when I follow his step 7. Build Debug/Release, I am getting the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CLSID_WbemLocator referenced in function "bool __cdecl base::win::CreateLocalWmiConnection(bool,class Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<struct IWbemServices> *)" (?CreateLocalWmiConnection@win@base@@YA_N_NPAV?$ComPtr@UIWbemServices@@@WRL@Microsoft@@@Z)   cefsimple   C:\Users\BremeyeT\source\repos\cef_binary_3.3538.1849.g458cc98_windows32\build\tests\cefsimple\cef_sandbox.lib(wmi.obj) 1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  cefsimple   C:\Users\BremeyeT\source\repos\cef_binary_3.3538.1849.g458cc98_windows32\build\tests\cefsimple\Debug\cefsimple.exe  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CLSID_WbemLocator referenced in function "bool __cdecl base::win::CreateLocalWmiConnection(bool,class Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<struct IWbemServices> *)" (?CreateLocalWmiConnection@win@base@@YA_N_NPAV?$ComPtr@UIWbemServices@@@WRL@Microsoft@@@Z)   cefclient   C:\Users\BremeyeT\source\repos\cef_binary_3.3538.1849.g458cc98_windows32\build\tests\cefclient\cef_sandbox.lib(wmi.obj) 1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  cefclient   C:\Users\BremeyeT\source\repos\cef_binary_3.3538.1849.g458cc98_windows32\build\tests\cefclient\Debug\cefclient.exe  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CLSID_WbemLocator referenced in function "bool __cdecl base::win::CreateLocalWmiConnection(bool,class Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<struct IWbemServices> *)" (?CreateLocalWmiConnection@win@base@@YA_N_NPAV?$ComPtr@UIWbemServices@@@WRL@Microsoft@@@Z)   ceftests    C:\Users\BremeyeT\source\repos\cef_binary_3.3538.1849.g458cc98_windows32\build\tests\ceftests\cef_sandbox.lib(wmi.obj)  1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ceftests    C:\Users\BremeyeT\source\repos\cef_binary_3.3538.1849.g458cc98_windows32\build\tests\ceftests\Debug\ceftests.exe
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741629/wmi-linker-error-on-x64) I learned that it has to do with wbemuuid.lib. So I added

> $(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)..\..\um\x86

to the Library Directories of the projects cefclient, cefsimple and ceftests, because this is where I found wbemuuid.lib on my drive. However the Cef library still does not compile successfully and shows the same errors.

I did check that I am compiling the Win32 version of the library and the wbemuuid.lib is the 32 bit version.

What else do I need to do to get a sucessful compile and link?

Comment: The instructions you've linked aren't actually for **building** `CEF`, they're just for compiling the wrapper and the test projects. If you don't need the test projects then just download a `Minimal Distribution` from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html

Comment: Minimal Distribution does compile. Thank you.

Comment: @amaitland: Would you be able to get CefSharp to compile with VS2017 as well?

Comment: `VS2017` is already supported when compiling `CefSharp`.

Comment: What is your reason for recompiling the `libcef_wrapper` in relation to `CefSharp`?

Comment: My mistake. I thought I needed it to get CefSharp to compile. But I was wrong. But I am getting `'AssemblyInfo': is not a class or namespace name` or `'AssemblyCompany': undeclared identifier`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to build from source instead of using one of the `Nuget` packages? See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#releases-1

Comment: For CefSharp3, I ended up commenting out all lines that had the AssemblyInfo errors. There were two more errors where an IntPrt had to convert to an int, which I did with .ToInt32(). Now I can compile and run the example applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with wbemuuid.lib